# Push data to web socket by triggering externally

Tags: javascript, web, websocket, socket.io

I want to push  data to to all the connected socket when a rest api is called

I have a express based node js application.

On App launch, I create the socket server as mentioned in the docs.

**Client Code**

```
var socket = io('http://localhost');
socket.emit('client_id', 'test');
socket.on('message', function (message) {
    console.log(message);
});
```

**Server Code**

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('client_id', function (client_id) {
        socket.join(client_id);
    });
});
```

**API Call**

```
io.sockets.to('client_name').emit('message', 'Some message');
```

The problem is, this works fine, when I start the node/socket server and launch the client.

But when I restart the node/socket server , the client no longer receives the message. I will have to reload the client to start receiving the message.

What could be the issue

Comment: Could you provide your client side code? Are you using the `socket.io` client or [WebSocket API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket)?

Comment: As I mentioned.. whatever mentioned in doc. Any way.. just updating

Comment: When I use `socket.io` library on both sides and when I stop the server and run it again all the clients automatically connect. The problem could come of the application design.

Comment: Ok, I'm sure that you want to wrap this code `socket.emit('client_id', 'test');` inside `socket.on('connect', function () {
                    socket.emit('client_id', 'test');
                });`

Comment: @codtex This issue gets solved when I put all the code inside 'on connect'. But, when the server restarts, the client creates a new connection and am getting message twice. if i restarts again, it triples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as [**commented**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45996107/push-data-to-web-socket-by-triggering-externally?noredirect=1#comment78953512_45996107) under the question I will try to explain what exactly happens with the code that you provided. Also I want to propose you with a solution to [**your comment**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45996107/push-data-to-web-socket-by-triggering-externally?noredirect=1#comment78955575_45996107)

```
// With the following line of code you connect to the server
var socket = io('http://localhost');

// Now you send the client_id and it is sent only once per page load
socket.emit('client_id', 'test');

// And here subscribe to the message event
socket.on('message', function (message) {
    console.log(message);
});

// ----------------------------------------
// now we change the above code like

var socket = io('http://localhost'); 
socket.on('connect', function(){
    // emit the event client_id every time you connect
    socket.emit('client_id', 'test');   
    socket.on('message', function (message) {
        console.log(message);
    }); 
});
```

You need to wrap your code inside `on('connect', ...)` subscription to make sure that every time you are connected to the server `client_id` is sent. Otherwise `client_id` is send only once when client code is loaded.

If you want to avoid double messages as stated in [**your comment**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45996107/push-data-to-web-socket-by-triggering-externally?noredirect=1#comment78955575_45996107), you can update the server side code like:

```
// Save reference to client_id by socket.id
var clientIds = {};
io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    socket.on('client_id', function (client_id) {
        clientIds[socket.id] = client_id;
        socket.join(client_id);
    });

    // Subscribe to disconnect event and leave the room once client is disconnected
    socket.on('disconnect', function (reason) {
        // leave the room
        socket.leave(clientIds[socket.id]);
    });

});
```

With the above code you make sure that you leave the rooms once a client is disconnected.

Let me know if something is not clear. Good luck!

Comment: That clears up thing. Thanks a lot. To sum up. 1. Place your code inside 'on connect', 2. Remove the connection manually using 'socket.id' during page refresh, to avoid duplicate connections;

Comment: You are welcome friend. I'm glad that this was helpful :)

Answer (score -2):

Every network connection has some state associated with it, which you most likely lose when you restart the server. Implementing a timeout and reconnecting to the server is one possible solution.